# How can I override the browser keyboard shortcuts in my GWT/GXT app?

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard-shortcuts, gxt

I'm using GWT and GXT and want to use keyboard shortcuts like CTRL-S (or CTRL-SHIFT-S)  to save the current form. Problem is, I can't figure out how to override the browsers built-in CTRL-S. I tried using a componentEvent and calling stopevent, cancelbubble, etc with no luck. I also tried using

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler(){  
}
```

and calling `event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();` to try and stop the event but that doesn't work either.

I'm at the point where i can get my keyboard shortcuts to work, but they also fire the browser's event too (like opens a browser save dialog)

Anyone have an idea/hint on how to get this to work? I actually have a number of shortcuts I want to use but many conflict with the browser - just trying to figure out how to override the browser's actions.

Comment: To answer my own question - we opted to go with CTRL+ALT shortcuts which don't conflict with any built-in browser keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to find key combinations rather than trying to override the keyboard shortcuts which is not a standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `preventDefault()` method on the KeyDownEvent. This works when I added a Dom Handler and also referenced from the javascript forums of how gmail does it - i have noticed that while CTRL-S does work, CTRL-N does not work in Chrome. Will be testing other browsers later.

Hope this helps,

Ian.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Chrome and Firefox. We were using KeyUpEvent but by then the browser save has already been triggered, switching to KeyDownEvent worked.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question - we opted to go with CTRL+ALT shortcuts which don't conflict with any built-in browser keyboard shortcuts.